# WearOS how to check is battery is plugged

Tags: android, wear-os, batterymanager

I'm developing a watch face that collects data.
In order to save battery, I'm storing data into an SQLite database.
I want to detect when the smart watch is plugged in in order to send the database from watch to phone.
I have succesfully implemented a service that sends the data.

I've added a broadcast receiver that should start the transfer of data, if the watch is plugged in. 
Edit: it is added as a member in class that extends `WearableListenerService`.

```
private BroadcastReceiver batReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "TEST");
    }
};
```

My problem is that `onReceive` does not get called. I have added the intent-filter to manifest:

```
<service android:name="si.ijs.maj.tictest.DBTService">

        <intent-filter>
            <!-- other stuff -->
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

tl;dr: My problem is that BroadcastReceiver doesn't do any receiving.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, the moment I asked a question I also solved the problem.
I had to register the receiver in Android and now it works.
Added code to `onCreate`:

```
// register battery receiver
registerReceiver(batReceiver, new IntentFilter(BatteryManager.ACTION_CHARGING));
```

And now the receiver is happily receiving.